# Magento 2.2.8 - Has Magento removed the Company field from the checkout?

Tags: checkout, magento2.2.8

For customers that have already saved their company information in their addresses, the company name does not show in the checkout.

Has anyone faced this issue before, with recent versions of Magento?
Are there any proposed fixes for this?

Comment: check your custom extension...because in fresh magento setup its completely work

Comment: Could you tell me which Magento files/templates are responsible for that?

Comment: you should check setting "Show Company" field on customer configuration or maybe your style is hiden this element.

Comment: Go to `Store >> Configuration >> CUSTOMERS >> Customer Configuration >> Name and Address Option >> Show Company` and check field is not disable from there

Comment: Already checked it, and it's set to 'Required'